# Solr with Django-Haystack: 'Cannot create tester'

Tags: django, shell, solr, django-haystack

I am trying to create a search engine with django haystack with solr. So far I followed the documentation below and installed solr-6.6.0 on my server.

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/installing_search_engines.html#solr

But with the command

`./bin/solr create -c tester -n basic_config`

I keep receiving the error:

`Failed to determine the port of a local Solr instance, cannot create tester!`

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use these commands:

```
$ cd solr
$ bin/solr start
```

your solr will run on 127.0.0.1:8983

to create an core:

```
$ bin/solr create -c <name>
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a core with the ***"solr"*** user:

**`sudo -u solr ./bin/solr create -c mycore`**

For the error: *"Failed to determine the port of a local Solr instance, cannot create tester!"* You need to stop and then start again your Solr service

> **`sudo service solr stop`** |
> **`sudo service solr start`**